# Possible FPU error

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, floating-point

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include  <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"
#include<stdlib.h>

int reg_a=7;
int reg_b=5;
int x= 0;
float y=0;
int main(void)
{
    x=reg_a+reg_b;
    y=reg_a+reg_b;//this line doesn't get executed. it enters the b Infinite_Loop 
}
```

I get the value of x as 12 but when the debugger executes 2nd line in main function it gets stuck in a b infinite loop in startup_stm32f401retx.s file.

I've noticed whenever a float calculation appears debugger gets stuck in 'b infinite loop'. below is that code snippet.

```
  .section .text.Default_Handler,"ax",%progbits
Default_Handler:
Infinite_Loop:
  b Infinite_Loop    //here the debugger is stuck
  .size Default_Handler, .-Default_Handler
```

I am using a stm32f401re and  it has a FPU.

edit:

This means the FPU is enabled right?

[image]

EDIT2: COMPLETE CODE

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include  <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "math.h"
#include<stdlib.h>

#define  SR_CC1IF  (1U<<1)
#define  SR_CC2IF  (1U<<2)
#define  SR_CC3IF  (1U<<3)
#define  SR_CC4IF  (1U<<4)
#define  SR_CC_ALL (SR_CC1IF | SR_CC2IF | SR_CC3IF | SR_CC4IF)

uint32_t reg_a=7;
uint32_t reg_b=5;
int reg_c=0;
int reg_d=4;

void tim2_all_channels_input_capture(void);

int x= 0;
float y=0;

int main(void)
{
    x=reg_c+reg_d;
    x=reg_a+reg_b;
    y=reg_a+reg_b; //HERE I GET THE DEFAULT HANDLER LOOP.IF I MAKE reg_c float then I get DEFAULT HANDLER ON THE FIRST LINE ITSELF.

    tim2_all_channels_input_capture();
    while(1)
    {


        volatile uint32_t sr = TIM1->SR;

        if((sr & SR_CC_ALL) == SR_CC_ALL)
        {
            x=x+1;
            reg_a =TIM1->CCR1;
            reg_b =TIM1->CCR2;
            reg_c =TIM1->CCR3;
            reg_d =TIM1->CCR4;
        }

    }
}


void tim2_all_channels_input_capture(void)
{
    RCC->APB2ENR  |= (1<<0) ;                //TIM1 CLOCK ENABLE
    RCC->AHB1ENR |=(1<<0) ;                //GPIOA CLOCK ENABLE

    GPIOA->MODER &=  ~(1<<16);  //PIN8
    GPIOA->MODER  |=  (1<<17);    // PIN8
    GPIOA->MODER &=  ~(1<<18); //PIN9
    GPIOA->MODER  |=  (1<<19);      //PIN9
    GPIOA->MODER &= ~ (1<<20);//PIN10
    GPIOA->MODER  |=  (1<<21);      //PIN10
    GPIOA->MODER &=  ~(1<<22);//PIN11
    GPIOA->MODER  |=  (1<<23);     //PIN11

    GPIOA->AFR[1]  |= (1U<<0);     //SET AS AF1 i.e TIM1 CH1
    GPIOA->AFR[1]  |= (1U<<4);     //SET AS AF1 i.e TIM1 CH2
    GPIOA->AFR[1]  |= (1U<<8);     //SET AS AF1 i.e TIM1 CH3
    GPIOA->AFR[1]  |= (1U<<12);   //SET AS AF1 i.e TIM1 CH4

    TIM1->PSC |= (1U<<0);  //DIVIDE BY 1

    TIM1->CCMR1  |= (1<<0);
    TIM1->CCMR1  &= ~(1<<1);
    TIM1->CCMR1  &= ~(1<<8);
    TIM1->CCMR1  |= (1<<9);

    TIM1->CCMR2  |= (1<<0);
    TIM1->CCMR2  &= ~(1<<1);
    TIM1->CCMR2  &= ~(1<<8);
    TIM1->CCMR2  |= (1<<9);


    TIM1->CCER |= (1U<<0);
    TIM1->CCER |= (1U<<4);
    TIM1->CCER |= (1U<<8);
    TIM1->CCER |= (1U<<12);

    TIM1->CR1 |=(1U<<0);

}
```

Comment: Make sure that the FPU is enabled.  What toolchain are you using?

Comment: `Infinite_Loop:` is STM32's "PC programmer" handler. Other toolchains are not as forgiving. Declare main like I already told you in a previous answer and then add a "forever loop".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE.

Comment: @Andyaka  This is an electronics problem. If I do this same thing on DEV C++ i wont get this problem .I am doing it on STM32(microcontroller)  that is when i get the problem.

Comment: @Lundin  This is just a snippet of the main function . Below these 2 lines there is a  while(1) loop. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: @kkrambo  I am using stm32IDE. I am using default toolchain. In project setting->mcu toolchain it mentions GNU Tools for STM32(11.3.rel1)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: [Defining variables in embedded c](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/687428/defining-variables-in-embedded-c)

Comment: @brhans yes it is , I thought I had not mentioned the problem clearly. So made 1 more question.

Comment: So post the real code causing the problem, not some other random code.

Comment: @Lundin  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79796/stm32-crashing-to-default-handler           This  is exactly the same problem .

Comment: Look, it is literally impossible to debug code without viewing the actual code. I cannot help you debug code x if you post code y. It would appear, by wild guessing, that you maybe have some missing interrupt handlers, as hinted at in the answers to that question. Or maybe some interrupt running in the background which doesn't handle stacking of floating point registers, so-called "lazy stacking". It's just guessing without the code.

Comment: @Lundin Added the complete code. My FPU enabled settings are right, right?

Comment: You told the compiler that the FPU is enabled, but since you're getting an exception on FP code you may not actually have it enabled or have configured it wrong.  Not familiar with this platform, but a very easy way to test would be to set the compiler to not use the hardware FPU.  If the code runs without using the hardware floating point unit, then probably the issue is that you don't have the FPU configured.

Comment: @user1850479  yes when i changed the setting to software implementation code runs perfectly fine. Ok so now ill have to see what else is rqued to enable fpu in stm32

Comment: @rachitjuthani - Hi, You should not have posted this improved version of your [previous, closed, question](/q/687428). Instead, the Stack Exchange approach is to edit a closed question to improve it, and if you have addressed the issues raised in comments there, then tick the "Submit for review" box just before clicking the "Save edits" button. That puts the edited question into the review queue, to possibly reopen it. However considering all the information now posted on *this* question, it's too late for you to follow that correct procedure and lose what's *here*. Don't do it again. Thanks

Comment: @Andyaka - Hi, You said: "*I’m voting to close this question because it's not about EE.*" Thanks for explaining the reason for your vote. However there are some non-EE topics, like firmware programming as in this question, which *are* [on-topic](/help/on-topic). Therefore being non-EE isn't a valid VTC reason on this question. || (Documenting for the record: The other VTC (due to this being a dup of the OP's previous question) has been addressed in my earlier comment. It's not sensible to waste site members' effort *here*, by closing this Q and forcing the OP to restart their prev question.)

Comment: @SamGibson my background reason was because the code being executed was the addition of integers 5 and 7 (using C) and, in my opinion that is not a valid EE subject for this site. For example, if I wrote similar code in java, would it form an acceptable question. I wasn't considering that the firmware programming was an issue to this site as there are many questions on firmware programming.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have defined __FPU_PRESENT preprocessor symbol, see for example image in last post of [this thread](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32cubeide-mcus/how-do-i-activate-the-fpu-on-f411/td-p/122394/page/2).

That is needed as the code to enable FPU is [compiled conditionally in SystemInit() function](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/cmsis_device_f4/blob/73273c20e85c6c57688f6106485a2e4f2592ddf9/Source/Templates/system_stm32f4xx.c#L170), called from the startup code.

Answer (score 0):

It stuck here because your program terminated. Add empty infinite loop at the end of main() function.

```
int main(void)
{
    x=reg_a+reg_b;
    y=reg_a+reg_b;
    
    while (1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually OK to omit `return` from `main()` (in both C++, and C as of C99) ([ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545291/can-i-omit-return-from-main-in-c) [ref2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) [ref3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function)). Then `return 0` is implied. On the other hand `void main()` is actually incorrect (not a standard signature, even if some compilers tolerate it; more specifically it's "implementation-defined").

Comment: @TypeIA true,i get a warning when i use void stating use int.

Comment: @TypeIA, thanks. I removed this misleading notice.

Comment: @Misaz the program is not terminating. There is a more stuff below.

Comment: Did you tried with added inifnite loop?

Comment: @TypeIA Embedded systems are freestanding systems, as far as the C standard is concerned. C17 5.1.2.1 "In a freestanding environment (in which C program execution may take place without any benefit
of an operating system), the name and type of the function called at program startup are implementation-defined."  So it is wrong say that `void main (void)` is incorrect - it is not a _strictly conforming program_ (C17 chp 4) but it is a _conforming program_.

Comment: @rachitjuthani You get a warning because you compile the program with the wrong options. I have already told you before that with gcc-like compilers you must compile embedded systems as `-ffreestanding`.

Comment: @Misaz Your previous notice was not misleading but correct. `void main (void)` should be used since this is not a PC.

Comment: @Lundin yes I know that from your other comment, that is why I have put int. It doesn't give any warnings or errors and i don't have to compile it differently.

Comment: @rachitjuthani But it causes stacking of return values inside the CRT before main() is called, so you just waste stack space for nothing. Why waste stack memory just for the heck of it?

Comment: @Lundin The STM32CubeIDE default setup code assumes `main` is the entry point (see [UM2609](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2609-stm32cubeide-user-guide-stmicroelectronics.pdf)) and is compatible with a _strictly conforming program_'s `main()` signature, so `-ffreestanding` is not needed here. The example programs and documentation also show a standard `main()` signature. So there's no reason not to use it here, and be strictly-compliant.

Comment: @TypeIA Compatible is one thing, sensible is another thing. Nothing stops you from writing `int main (void) { waste_of_space(); }` and then implement everything in `waste_of_space` either, forever leaving the stacked call parameters behind. If you have some aversion towards available stack space, that's the way to go. If you want to use as much of the stack as possible, then use `void main (void)`. To spell it out, single step through the CRT on the assembler level and check what it does before calling main(). Is it stacking data? Will that memory ever get returned to you?

Comment: @TypeIA Also note that the document you link is written by one of them "C/C++" people who don't quite know what they are talking about. C++, unlike C, enforces the form `int main()` in case there exists a function named `main` in the program. Basically the C++ standard goes like "yeah we know that there are freestanding programs but we don't really care". Therefore freestanding C++ programs have to declare their entry function as something else.

Comment: void/int main() change nothing because return value is (or is not) passed in register r0. main is not pure entry point. ST mention this because their startup file (assembler) calls main like it was entry point.

Comment: @Misaz Looking at a CRT (not by ST) for a STM32 M0 right now - yeah it uses r0 but it also saves r0 down after calling main(), since it expects the program to return at some point. The implication that you expect to return from main() is the problem: so main() needs to stack all callee registers for the rainy day when it will return to the CRT. With `void` you could give further hints such as `_Noreturn void main (void)` and then prevent needless stacking of crap. I don't remember all the dirty details of the most common ABI for Cortex M, but I remember that it is callee-stacking oriented.

Comment: @Lundin: The caller only has to stack `r0` when calling `int main(void)` if the register allocator / liveness analysis shows that `r0` is holding some value that's needed later.  If `r0` is not allocated to anything at the point of the call, there's no need to save and restore it.  (Since there's nothing but an infinite loop after the call, `r0` is not holding any value that's "needed later")

Comment: While this answer shows a way of reaching an infinite loop, it is not relevant to the evidence in the question.  Two things contradict the assumption this answer makes about reaching the end of main.  (1) the change in behavior between soft float and hard float.  (2) the call stack shown in the question (behind the project properties)

Comment: @BenVoigt The question was edited several times since original posting. Original question contained very simplified code and it missed screenshot. This answer is not valid anymore, but at least discussion under it contains some valuable information.

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked the timestamps.  If you add an introductory sentence explaining you're presenting a different case with similar symptoms, I'll change my vote to an upvote.

Comment: @BenVoigt In the CRT I checked, `atexit` as well as C++ destructors were executed after main(). Not very sensible in an embedded system, but neither is returning from main() in the first place...

Comment: @Lundin: But the signal return address is into `main()`, not `atexit` or CRT support code